# Cannot create Google Cloud Serverless VPC Connector using default parameters

Tags: google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I am following these instructions:  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector

Every time I create a connector, I get the red exclamation point with an error saying: "Connector is in a bad state, recommend manual deletion"

[image: screenshot of bad connector]

I am using the following parameters:

- us-central1
- default network
- 10.8.0.0
- 200mbps min, 300mbps max

I have also tried 10.0.0.0 and 10.64.0.0, based on threads I've read elsewhere.  Nothing is working.

I do not have a complicated network setup.  When I view my VPC Networks, I see:

[image: my vpc default network]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless VPC Access [does not support legacy networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access). Your "default" network mode is Legacy.

Serverless VPC Access supports Shared VPC and communication to networks connected via Cloud Interconnect, Cloud VPN, and VPC Network Peering.

You may want to set up [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) and verify the steps provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#troubleshooting) to create connector correctly. Additionally, check out the [supported regions](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#supported_regions) for Serverless VPC Access connector.